# ASP.Net Core API response takes too much time

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I have a SQL database table with 9000 rows and 97 columns. Its primary key has 2 columns: `Color` and `Name`. You can see the simplified table to image better:

[image]

I have an ASP.NET Core API listening at URL `api/color/{colorName}`, it reads the table to get color information. Currently I have 3 colors and about 3000 rows each.

It takes too much time. It reads table in 2383ms and maps to DTO in 14ms. And after that I immediately return the DTO to consumer but somehow the API takes 4135.422ms. I don't understand why. I guess I should take 2407.863ms but it not. It takes almost 2 times more.

You can see my code and logs below. Do you have an idea how can I improve the response time?

I use Entity Framework Core 3.1, AutoMapper and ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Service:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ColorDTO>> GetColors(string requestedColor)
{
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var colors = await _dbContext.Colors.Where(color => color.color == requestedColor).ToListAsync();
    watch.Stop();
    _logger.LogError("Color of:{requestedColor} Reading takes:{elapsedMs}", requestedColor, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);


    var watch2 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var colorDtos = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ColorDTO>>(colors);
    watch2.Stop();
    _logger.LogError("Color of:{requestedColor} Mapping takes:{elapsedMs}", requestedColor, watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    return colorDtos;
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ColorDTO>>> GetBlocksOfPanel(string requestedColor)
{
    return Ok(await _colorService.GetColors(requestedColor));
}
```

And the logs:

```
2020-04-27 15:21:54.8793||0HLVAKLTJO59T:00000003|MyProject.Api.Services.IColorService|INF|Color of Purple Reading takes:2383ms
2020-04-27 15:21:54.8994||0HLVAKLTJO59T:00000003|MyProject.Api.Services.IColorService|INF|Color of Purple Mapping takes:14ms
2020-04-27 15:21:54.9032||0HLVAKLTJO59T:00000003|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|INF|Executed action method MyProject.Api.Web.Controllers.ColorsController.GetColors (MyProject.Api.Web), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult in 2407.863ms.
2020-04-27 15:21:54.9081||0HLVAKLTJO59T:00000003|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor|INF|Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyProject.Api.Contracts.Dtos.ColorDTO, MyProject.Api.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
2020-04-27 15:21:56.4895||0HLVAKLTJO59T:00000003|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|INF|Executed action MyProject.Api.Web.Controllers.ColorsController.GetColors (MyProject.Api.Web) in 4003.8022ms
2020-04-27 15:21:56.4927||0HLVAKLTJO59T:00000003|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware|INF|Executed endpoint 'MyProject.Api.Web.Controllers.ColorsController.GetColors (MyProject.Api.Web)'
2020-04-27 15:21:56.4972||0HLVAKLTJO59T:00000003|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|INF|Request finished in 4135.422ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: you also need to account for latency in your transaction between the service and your consumer which is where the extra time may be coming form. Do you really need to return all of the rows for a color at one time or can you add take and skip so you are only returning 200 or X at a time and the consumer can call back for another set starting at the previous point if they need to

Comment: I don't know the mapper (Automapper?) but EF at least takes extra time to compile a query the first time you run it, but only the first time. Is a second request still as slow?

Comment: Its Automapper. And this is not first time query, the first query takes 8 seconds. And I really have to send it at one time.

Comment: I investigated your code. It seems that everything is ok. You should take a print screen of your SQL diagram. I am sure that your problem relates SQL side.

Answer (score 2):

As @ejwill mentioned in his comment, you need to consider latency in the entire operation. Fetching from the database and mapping to DTOs is only part of what is happening during the round trip of the request and response to your API.

You can probably reduce the the query time against your database table through some optimizations there. You don't indicate what database you're using, but a composite key based on two string/varchar values may not necessarily be the most performant, and the use of indexes on values you're filtering on may also help -- there are tradeoffs there depending on whether you're optimizing for write or for read. That being said, 97 columns is not trivial either way. Do you need to query and return all 97 columns over the API? Is pagination an option?

If you must return all the data for all 97 columns at once and you're querying the API frequently, you can also consider the use of an in-memory cache, especially if the table is not changing often; instead of making the roundtrip to the database every time, you keep a copy of the data in memory so it can be returned much more quickly. You can look at an implementation of an in-memory cache that supports a generational model to keep serving up data while new versions are fetched.

https://github.com/jfbosch/recache

Answer (score 1):

Serialization of result could take huge time.

First thing is serialization itself: if you return 3k records, it will take significant time to serialize it to JSON or XML. Consider moving to more compact binary formats.

Second thing is memory and GC. If amount of **serialized** data exceeds 85,000 bytes, memory for this data will be allocated on LOH in one chunk. This could take time. You might consider inspecting your LOH and look for response data stored there. Possible workaround could be responding with chunks of data and utilization of kind of paging with `offset` and `position`.

You can easily check that serialization causes performance trouble: leave call to DB as it is, but return to the client only 100-200 rows instead of the whole result, or return less object fields (for example, only 3). Time should be reduced.

Answer (score -1):

your problem relates to SQL side. you should check the indexing of your columns and run your query in the execution plan state to find your bottleneck. Also, for increasing performance, I suggest that rewrite code in the async state.

Comment: Alireza joon, It's already using async methods. Did you read the code?